# Google Auth token gets expired within windows service

Tags: google-oauth

I implemented a windows service which downloads DoubleClick report data for several DFA accounts. The windows service is installed twice on the same server but the services import the downloaded reports into different SQL server (dev and live). Both services run daily at a specific time but not parallel. The windows service uses the the DFA Reporting API 1.3. and the Google APIs Client Library 1.7 (beta).

The first day after restarting the windows services all data will be loaded without any errors but the next days I get an "Authentication token has expired" error. This is the code

```
public ImportData(string loginUserName, string sourceName)
{
    Logger.Info(string.Format("Import for Source {0} started.", sourceName));

    this.dbContext = new DatabaseContext();

    // Create new log item
    this.importExportLog = this.dbContext.ImportExportLogs.Create();
    this.importExportLog.SetData("DoubleClick " + sourceName, DateTime.Now);

    this.dbContext.ImportExportLogs.Add(this.importExportLog);
    this.dbContext.SaveChanges();

    this.StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(0 - DoubleClickImporterSettings.Default.ImportDataForDays);
    this.EndDate = DateTime.Today;

    this.userName = loginUserName;
    this.sourceName = sourceName;

    // Reset report data
    campaignObjs = new List<Campaign>();
    clientObjs = new List<Advertiser>();
    siteObjs = new List<DfaSite>();
    adObjs = new List<AdBase>();

    this.user = new DfaUser();

    ClientSecrets secret = new ClientSecrets();
    secret.ClientId = this.user.Config.OAuth2ClientId;
    secret.ClientSecret = this.user.Config.OAuth2ClientSecret;

    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secret, new string[] { DfaReportingScope }, this.user.Config.OAuth2PrnEmail, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(DoubleClickImporterSettings.Default.OAuthStorePath)).Result;
    // Keep auth toke for 6 hours
    credential.Token.ExpiresInSeconds = 21600;

        // Create the dfa reporting service.
        DfareportingService dfars = new DfareportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Double Click Importer",
            });

    // log in for dfa api 
    if ((user.Config as DfaAppConfig).AuthorizationMethod == DfaAuthorizationMethod.OAuth2)
    {
    // Set the OAuth2 scope.
    user.Config.OAuth2Scope = DfaReportingScope;

    // Since we are using a console application, set the callback url to null.
    user.Config.OAuth2RedirectUri = null;
    }
    else
    {
    throw new Exception("Authorization mode is not OAuth2.");
    }

    // Set the username. This is required for the LoginService to work
    // correctly when authenticating using OAuth2.
    (user.Config as DfaAppConfig).DfaUserName = userName;

    this.user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();

    startDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    ImportReportData(dfars);

    this.user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();

    while (!ImportClientData(user))
    {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitUntilNextTry);
    this.user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();
    }

    this.user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();

    while (!ImportAdvertiserData(user))
    {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitUntilNextTry);
    this.user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();
    }

    // Import other data...
}
```

Why the error doesn't occur on first day but occur on the other days?

Comment: I believe the access token is only 3600secs.  If you need your token to live beyond that time, you need to refresh the access token with a refresh token.  Here is also a list of reasons why tokens expired:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration

Comment: Yes, the access token is valid for only 3600 seconds. That's the reason why I make a token refresh after every API call by

this.user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken(); 

It's possible that the refresh request contains a bug so the token will not be refreshed?

Comment: No idea why the access token gets expired?

Comment: just so that i understand... did you create a brand new refresh token everytime when you refresh the access token?

Comment: The reason I asked is because there is a short term quota to how many refresh tokens you can generate. I don't know the daily cap for it, but the refresh tokens should be cached forever but access tokens should be cached for 1hr

Comment: As I mentioned in my first post I'm using the DFA Reporting API 1.3 and Google APIs Client Library 1.7 (beta). The DFA Reporting API 1.3 is used for generating and downloading DFA reports. The Google APIs Client Library 1.7 (beta) is used for downloading DFA data like clients, campaigns, etc. Both API's do have there own refresh token and access token. One refresh token will be stored in the app.config and the other will be stored in a file. On refreshing the the access token the refresh token will not be overwritten. This means the refresh token will be cached forever.

Comment: Maybe the problem occurs because I'm using two API's with their own authentication routine? But why the first day after restarting the windows service the error doesn't occur?

I implemented as small batch file which restarts the windows service every day. This way the error doesn't occur but it's not a solution.